# XAMPP SSL Certificate better hash security

Tags: ssl, xampp

I was wondering if there's a way to generate a new SSL certificate for XAMPP. I get a lot of SHA-1 warnings in the firebug console and I think it's because of using SSL which has sha1 as algorithm.

However, I can't seem to find how to generate a new certificate with a better hash. If I'm saying things that makes no sense, please don't hate on me as I've never worked with SSL certificates before.

Also, I cannot suppress the warnings as I use firebug and the warnings just makes my POST files harder to find.

Answer (score 7):

I followed the instructions there to generate a new, self-signed certificate for 127.0.0.1 and localhost: https://notepad.patheticcockroach.com/3054/how-to-create-and-install-an-apache-ssl-certificate-either-self-signed-or-not/
I just needed to add "-sha256" as an argument when generating the CSR and signing, so basically:

```
openssl genrsa -des3 -out server.key 3072
openssl req -new -sha256 -key server.key -out server.csr
openssl x509 -req -sha256 -days 11000 -in server.csr -signkey server.key -out server.crt
```

Then use those files to replace the files with same names located in apache\conf\ssl.crt, apache\conf\ssl.csr and apache\conf\ssl.key

Or you can just use my files:

This is server.crt:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

This is server.csr

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----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-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
```

And this is server.key:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Comment: If you want "better security", surely using certificates and keys that someone posted publicly would be a Very Bad Idea.

Comment: Well if I understand well, the OP's issue is the warning spam in Firebug caused by SHA-1 signed certificates, like this https://i.imgur.com/P119Sag.png
Also as far as I know the default XAMPP certificates and keys are very much public too. But yeah, the point is not "better security" indeed, it's more "make my debugging tool readable again" ;)

Comment: Thank you for posting the certificates! Perfect and quick solution for my sandbox which is not public.

Comment: Perfect!!! Thank you... I just replaced my cert's with yours and cleaned up my console. Thanks so much!  Obviously don't use this on a public server, but for local dev that's a great solution.

Comment: Actually just used your solution again... thank you so much! This is so useful...